# Drag-and-Drop not working for Qt Widgets Application captured and embedded using QWidget::createWindowContainer

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have an application that is capturing and embedding another application using `QWidget::createWindowContainer`. Here's the code responsible for this:

```
void MainWindow::capture( WId wid )
{
    auto window = QWindow::fromWinId( wid );
    auto widget = QWidget::createWindowContainer( window );
    ui->ContentFrame->layout()->addWidget( widget );
}
```

The application is captured and added to the layout successfully, but drag-and-drop does not work within the captured application. When dragging a widget the cursor displays an X while the widget is held over the captured application, and dropping results in nothing.

I have tried to ensure that drag-and-drop is actually enabled using both `setAcceptsDrops()` and `setAttribute( Qt::WA_AcceptDrops )` on the newly created widget, the widget it is being embedded into, and the capturing dialog, but none of this seems to make a difference.

Drag-and-drop does work for the captured application when launched on its own and not captured. It seems to be the capturing process that breaks the drag-and-drop. Is there something I need to manually do to ensure it works in my scenario?

Some additional information: I am developing with Qt 5.5.1 on Ubuntu 16.04. The application being captured is started using a `QProcess` in the capturing application.